# How to store locations in ArangoDB?

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, arangodb, aql, document-database

I am building a web application where I need to store a large number of unique addresses as nodes in **ArangoDB**.

One approach would be using a hierarchical graph model: a *country* node connected to *county* nodes, *county* nodes connected to *cities* and *cities* connected to exact *addresses* with GeoJSON attributes.

The other option would be having only address nodes which contain city, county and country as attributes.

Which method would be more beneficial? I would be running queries to find locations in a given range or locations in a given city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's see what you will need in terms of collections to build your app:

1. Collection storing the Places you want to use in your app. This would be your main collection and would contain among other things a map location object {longitude: XXX, Latitude YYY}
2. Because you probably want people to be able to search by city, country, etc.. You need either a collection per Location type (city, country, etc) or a table with all the locations and a "type" flag that indicates the location is city or country, etc....

3.- You need a table that allows you to start at a country and drill down to a particular set of cities (for example). So, you need a table with a from key and a to key

By this point you probably have noticed that we have basically built a hierarchy, which in Arango I would build as at least one Places vertex collection, a Locations vertex collection and a locationContains edge collection. This would allow for really fast lookups and is one of the reasons why graph databases were originally created.

Now note that since Arango is a multi model DB, you can use the graph syntax (I like anonymous graph syntax myself), but you can also use traditional joins whenever needed, which behave very similar to a traditional relational DB.